# Libreoffice: How do I covert .xlsx to .pdf format in command line with Khmer Unicode?

Tags: excel, pdf, unicode, command-line, libreoffice

Currently, I use this commandline to convert from excel file to pdf file.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir . excel-file.xlsx
```

But the problem is there are not stable with Khmer Unicode (Cambodian) Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can get proper Khmer Unicode render by set the "Complex Text Layout" to "Khmer".

To access this command,

Choose **LibreOffice** - **Preferences** - **Language Settings** - **Languages** - **Complex Text Layout**.